# How many different ways can you draw a line that divides the configuration of $n\times n$ points into two equal sets?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

If we have a configuration of $n \times n$ points (the configuration is just a regular square grid graph) where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how many different ways can we draw a line into this configuration that crosses at least two points symmetrically so that this line divides this set of points into two separate sets that have the same cardinality? An example of this kind of a line would be the diagonal.

My initial idea was to go through the points at the outer edges one by one and find a general rule. However, I was struggling to do this and realized there are other points too that may determine this line. I was also considering just going by enumeration, but it looks very tedious.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, the answer is trivially 0.

Comment: What do you do when a 3rd point lies on the line? Which set of points does it get put into?

Comment: What does it mean to "cross at least two points _symmetrically_"? You mean the line goes through two points?

Comment: Yes, that was a weird expression. But what I meant was that the line has to go through at least 2 (or more) points in the configuration.

Comment: For the case when $n$ is even, it's tricky. I think it will depend on how many points are collinear with each other.

Comment: The collinearities are determined by the fact that the configuration is basically the vertices of a regular square grid graph.

Comment: @SenZen If $n$ is odd, all lines that divide the grid symmetrically pass through the central point. There are  four lines that divide a $3\times 3$ grid into two sets of three points.

Comment: @Daniel Mathias The line must go through 2 points, not divide the grid symmetrically?

Comment: @SenZen *At least* two points. Draw a $3\times 3$ grid and a vertical line through the center. The line passes through three points and separates the remaining points into two sets of three.